# How to get all docs ID in Firebase and list them in Firebase Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to list all  documents's ID from my Firebase collection (type double). How can I do that? I've done just manually, one by one, just like the example bellow. Is there any way to get all the documents programmatically?

```
  _listDocsFirebase() async {
    var myCollection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('produtos');
    var docSnapshot = await myCollection.doc("AdK3winWyT7LQmpzU621").get();
    if (docSnapshot != null) {
      Map<String, dynamic>? data = docSnapshot.data();
      var value = data?['preco']; //
      print('######################### ${value}');
    }
  }
```

Comment: Did you see the Firebase documentation on getting all documents from a collection: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_all_documents_in_a_collection?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've just edited my question because I found out that what I need is the list of IDs of all docs, so I can access them. Unfortunally,, I haven't found a doc or answer for that yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get all documents in a collection

```
var querySnapshot = await db.collection("produtos").get();
querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {
  print('${doc.id} => ${doc.data()}');
})
```